# Convert array to string

Tags: php, string

I have an array of strings and I need to build a string of values separated by some 
character like comma

```
$tags;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 18):

There is a simple function called [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$string = implode(';', $array);
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [implode](http://us.php.net/implode) function.

For example, `implode(' ',$tags);` will place a space between each item in the array.

Answer (score 2):

If any one do not want to use implode so you can also use following function:

```
function my_implode($separator,$array){
   $temp = '';


   foreach($array as $key=>$item){
       $temp .=  $item; 
       if($key != sizeof($array)-1){
            $temp .= $separator  ; 
       }
   }//end of the foreach loop

   return $temp;
}//end of the function

$array = array("One", "Two", "Three","Four");


$str = my_implode('-',$array);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an function [**`join`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) which is an alias of implode.

Answer (score 0):

Using [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$array_items = ['one','two','three','four']; 
$string_from_array = implode(',', $array_items);

echo $string_from_array;
//output: one,two,three,four
```

Using [join](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) (alias of implode)

```
$array_items = ['one','two','three','four']; 
$string_from_array = join(',', $array_items);

echo $string_from_array;
//output: one,two,three,four
```