# convert array into string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like in PHP:

```
$a = array('110','111','121');
```

i want to convert it to :

```
$b = " '110' , '111' , '121' ";
```

is there any function in PHP that does it? i know it could be done with a loop on array and put value in $b, but i want a less more code solution.

thank you.

Comment: definite duplicate of [convert array to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237211/convert-array-to-string) and [merge array items into string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626732/merge-array-items-into-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do need all those spaces and quotes? You can still use `implode`, although `array_reduce` might be nicer

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$x = "'".implode("' , '", $a)."'";
```

`array_reduce`:

```
$x = array_reduce($a, function($b, $c){return ($b===null?'':$b.' , ')."'".$c."'";});
```

Advantage of `array_reduce`, is that you will get NULL for an empty array, instead of `''`. Note that you cannot use this inline function construct in php versions prior to 5.3. You'll need to make the callback a separate function and pass its name as a string to array_reduce.

Comment: Getting NULL over getting an empty string isnt exactly an advantage. You have to check the return type instead of just being able to work with it. Having functions return a single type is always the better choice.

Comment: You're not getting an empty string, you're getting a string containing two quotes. :) So'll you'd probably still have to check for that. If so, checking for null is more logical and convenient than checking for some obscure content like two single quotes. Of course, you could always choose to implode first and add the quotes afterwards. Or you could typecast the result of array_reduce to *string* which will convert your NULL to an empty string.

Comment: you are getting the quoted string because your implementation is flawed. functions and methods should not return null. let them return a [null object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceNullObject.html) - or in this case, an empty string. when you return null, you are effectively returning a status message the developer has to check on.

Answer (score 4):

yes, check implode -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 3):

well this is a different approach

```
$arraystring = print_r($your_array, true);
```

and if you want to print it somewhere else formated then

```
$arraystring = '<pre>'.print_r($your_array, true).'</pre>';
```

or you could mix many arrays and vars if you do this

```
ob_start();
print_r($var1);
print_r($arr1);
echo "blah blah";
print_r($var2);
print_r($var1);
$your_string_var = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

```
$b = " '" . implode("' , '", $a) . "' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Very nice outup gives

```
$arraystring = json_encode($your_array);
```