# How can i cover array to string int?

Tags: php

i have a array and how can i cover it to string fastest ?

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1,
    [2] => 8,
    [3] => 10,
    [4] => 16,
)
```

I need cover it to this string $var = (1,8,10,16)

Comment: Do you mean "convert"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237211/convert-array-to-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array to String PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490488/array-to-string-php)

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626732/merge-array-items-into-string) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007598/convert-array-into-string-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Just implode it:

```
$var = '(' . implode(',', $data) . ');
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/9bsZF

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple implode function for that .

```
    $arr = array(
        "1" => 1,
        "2" => 8,
        "3" => 10,
        "4" => 16
        );
echo implode($arr, ",");
```

output : 1,8,10,16

OR

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
     echo $value .", ";
 }
```

Output : 1, 8, 10, 16,