# PHP: Turn array into string?

Tags: php, arrays, debugging

I have a problem: I need to turn an array into a string and pass it to a function for debugging output.

I cannot directly output the string with `print_r`, I need to join it with some other strings and **pass it to a function**.

Google did not bring any results that display the array in a human-readable way without directly printing them. I need a string which I can pass to another function.

Comment: try implode() and show also you expected output with code

Comment: Please post a sample string, your expected output and the code you've tried so far to achieve the result.

Comment: You could use `$str = print_r($someData,true)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert array to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237211/convert-array-to-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `print_r()` function like this:

```
$myarray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$string = print_r($myarray, true);
echo $string;
```

The optional boolean flag as second parameters makes the function return a string instead of directly sending it to the output.

Comment: To show it in a formatted manner, you can wrap it around '<pre>' tags:

$string = '<pre>' . print_r($myarray, true) . '</pre>';

Comment: @SupriyaRajgopal Sure, but that is not the goal here (according to the OP) and, important, that only works for HTML based output, so only if you use a browser. Such attempts don't make sense in other situations, for example when using PHP an CLI.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r` uses an optional parameter to set to true to return the string instead of outputting it :

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar', array('baz' => true, 'test' => 42));
$stringifiedArray = print_r($array, true);
/* $stringifiedArray == "
    Array
    (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => bar
        [2] => Array
            (
                [baz] => 1
                [test] => 42
            )

    )
"
*/
```

Otherwise, I can see two ways, but both are not as easily readable by a human :

- `json_encode` :

`$stringifiedArray = json_encode($array, true);
// $stringifiedArray == "["foo","bar",{"baz":true,"test":42}]"`

- `serialize` :

`$stringifiedArray = serialize($array, true);
// $stringifiedArray == "a:3:{i:0;s:3:"foo";i:1;s:3:"bar";i:2;a:2:{s:3:"baz";b:1;s:4:"test";i:42;}}"`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `<?php implode(', ', $array); ?>`