# write variable array in one string

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

I have got an array with variable number of strings.

I need to write each element, separated with comma as one string in a variable.

With "foreach()" I got every element in a separate line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert array to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237211/convert-array-to-string)

Comment: please read the php docs and/or learn how to search....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the snippet below:

```
implode(',', $array);
```

[php.net-Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)